# sitelink searchbox for opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, header, opencart, schema.org, opencart2.x

Hey I am using opencart 2.0.3.1 and I want to put the schema.org markup in the header of my opencart site, I just pasted inside header.php (which you can find in catalog/controller/common/header.php ) I added the schema.org markup just below

```
$data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();
```

and also added

```
<?php if($sitelinks_search_box) echo $sitelinks_search_box; ?> 
just below <base href="<?php echo $base; ?>"
```

which is in header.tpl

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl
```

but still not able to get the schema.org source when I view the source! Someone please help.

Comment: Can you show the script example which you want to add and why you want to use this script ?

Comment: The script is <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script> and want to use it for the sitelinksearchbox as read here https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview#how_do_you_set_it_up

Comment: @zedBlackbeard Awaiting your reply sir!